# GuzzleHttps - How to send async. data via POST (using Pool)

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to send POST data via POOL in Guzzle Library. But, at the address where the data is sending POST is completely empty -  I don't get it.

```
$client = new Client();

$requests = function ()
{
    foreach($this->urls as $url)
    {
        yield new Request('POST', $url, [
            'body' => '...'
        ]);
    }
 };
```

I tried also form_params and multiparts, does not working again (POST is empty again also $_REQUEST & $_GET).

And of course this piece of code (for completeness):

```
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(), [
    'concurrency' => count($this->urls),
    'fulfilled'   => function ($response) {},
    'rejected' => function ($reason) {},
});

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();
```

Guzzle sends the request correctly (enter on the second server), but in itself does not have any data.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm just trying replace this code with Guzzle (is repeated in a cycle now):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://example.cop';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'mehehe_net');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 59000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$dt = ["data" => json_encode($queue)];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dt);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$cont = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution working GREAT! :-)

```
$pss = [];
$client = new Client();
$uri = "https://example.com";
foreach($data as $alarm)
{
    $pss[] = $client->postAsync($uri, ['form_params' => ["alarms" => json_encode($alarm)]])->then(function ($response) use ($alarm)
    {
         // $response->getBody();
    });
 }
 \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($permis);
```

Do not forget use unwrap (wait) after the loop! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I used.

```
$requests = function ($endpoints, $data) {

            foreach ($endpoints as $endpoint) {
                yield new Psr7\Request(
                   'POST', 
                   $endpoint, 
                   ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
                   http_build_query($data, null, '&'));
            }
            echo "\n";
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information to your solution: consider to use `each_limit()` with a generator instead of `unwrap`.

It will allow you to control concurrency level (amount of parallel queries). It's useful when you have big amount of requests and some restrictions on the server side (usually there are some restrictions about number of simultaneous requests from a client).

```
$generator = function () {
    return $client->postAsync($uri, ['form_params' => ["alarms" => json_encode($alarm)]])->then(function ($response) {
        // ...
    });
}

// Allow only 10 simultaneous requests.
each_limit($generator(), 10)->wait();
```

Read [this article](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/) for more details.